# Oh why, $.post function

Tags: jquery, ajax

Some time now that I am struggling with this function. Here is an example:

HTML example code:

```
    <form method="POST">            
        <label>Input 1:</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="Input1" id="Input1"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" id="Login"/>
    </form>
```

PHP example code (script.php):

```
    if(isset($_POST['Input1Php']))
    {   
        $Input1 = $_POST['Input1Php'];

        if($Input1 == "Random Condition")
        {
            echo "All good";
        }else
        {
            echo "Hell no!";
        }
    }
```

jQuery example code (I also tried with .submit(), doesn't change anything):

```
$('#Login').click(function()
{
    var Input1JS = $('#Input1 ').val();

    if("Something"=="Random Condition")
    {   
        $.post('script.php',{Input1Php:Input1JS},function(data)
        {
            if(data=="All good")
            {
                   Show me that
            }else
            {
                   Show me this
            }
        });
    }else
    {
        Just don't do anything
    }
});
```

This script works find with .keyup, etc but when I change it to click or submit, it just doesn't do anyhting. I don't understand why. Am I missing something? Does $.post just don't work with those events?

PS: Please, don't change the $.post to something else. My point is to understand how or if THIS function works with those events.

Comment: maybe because "Something" isn't equal to "Random Condition" ? and how does it work with .keyup? you're binding it to click. Add relevant code or refine your question

Comment: Well if "Something" isn't equal to "Random Condition", it should do the "Just don"t do anything" part. But it doesn't. If I change $('#Login').click(function()
to $('#Input1').keyup(function(), it works ...

Comment: do you mean it doesn't trigger the event? And what does actually happens? do you get an error?

Comment: add 'alert('x')' just before the if and check if anything happens

Comment: Alerts right. And if I alert between the If and $.post, also.

Comment: see @Nikola Radosavljević answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having that your question lacks some information, it's possible that your page is posting back so it doesn't wait for `$.post` to return. Try changing

```
<input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" id="Login"/>
```

to

```
<input type="button" name="Login" value="Login" id="Login"/>
```

and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The browser usually has some default action for buttons. In this case, the post data will be submitted by traditional means. If you want to prevent this behavior, just add a `return false;` at the end of your `click` callback.